# Always specify complete path to gcloud

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I am totally a newbie to Google App Engine, and I am trying to learn GAE. I have installed gcloud command line into my MAC, but every time I want to run a console command, to deploy or install from component manager, I always give the complete path to the sdk bin like this

```
./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
```

I have checked my $PATH variable and the google-cloud-sdk/bin is specified. Am I missing anything?

Comment: yep, you are.. May I know the directory where you run the above command? You have to append the gcloud complete path to the global path variable.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I run this command in the google-cloud-sdk/bin directory. And I have also appended the gcloud complete path to global path

Ramjis-MacBook-Air:AndroidStudioProjects ramajseepha$ echo $PATH
/Users/ramajseepha/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin